# Macro How to write into a selected cell in a sheet

Tags: vba

I want when I turn on the macro, it will write the result into a previously selected cell in the sheet

That is, the cell with the green frame at this moment

What is the parameter of this?

```
dim abc as range
abc = range.select
```

Comment: Look into `With Selection`. Relying on `.Select` is rarely a good thing. What are you trying to do? You may want to consider a worksheet change/Selection change event

Comment: So... What cell would you _like it to write to_?

Comment: I have the same amount of codes activated when you click on a particular cell, and present the result of the macro (form) in the same cell, I thought that if I have a parameter set by the currently selected cell, resigned from duplicates of codes

Comment: [`Range.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.select) doesn't return anything. You can't assign from it.

Comment: That's why I have a question

Comment: Use the macro recorder to capture your steps, then study the code that's generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Selection.Value = yourResultHere
```

Might be worth adding a check using `TypeName(Selection)` in case the user has something else selected (such as a shape/chart/etc)